# How to customize UITableView and its cell to get clear color separator and different length of the cell depends on the title?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift5

So far I have 7 tableview cells with no separator and fixed length for all of them. How do 1) add some clear color separators in between them and 2) set the cells background color to orange but the color should only be under the label which the text will have different length?

Here is my current code:

```
class CafesView: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    let cafes = [
        "Banana Joe's",
        "College Eight Cafe",
        "Global Village",
        "Iveta",
        "Stevenson Coffee House",
        "Terra Fresca",
        "Vivas"
    ]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 7
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cafesCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cafeCell", for: indexPath)
        cafesCell.textLabel?.text = cafes[indexPath.row]
        return cafesCell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return tableView.frame.height / 7
    }

    @IBAction func closeTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        self.backgroundColor = .systemOrange
        self.roundCorners(corners: [.topLeft, .bottomLeft], radius: 10)

   }

}
```

Comment: What I've done in the past, when I want control over the separators, is disable them in the `UITableView/Controller` and then add a 1point high `UIView` to the `superview.bottom` of the `UITableCellView`.  I can then control the width and color as needed

Comment: 1. Set the tableView.separatorStyle to .none. 
2. Set the background color of the label instead of setting the background color for cell. Else you also add a UIView below the label and set its background color to orange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line to remove separator line

```
tableView.separatorStyle = .none
```

And, add one label (here i added `lblCafes`) in `UITableViewCell` and set label background color to orange color.

Your code will be,

```
    class CafesView: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

        @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

        let cafes = [
            "Banana Joe's",
            "College Eight Cafe",
            "Global Village",
            "Iveta",
            "Stevenson Coffee House",
            "Terra Fresca",
            "Vivas"
        ]

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            tableView.separatorStyle = .none

            tableView.delegate = self
            tableView.dataSource = self
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return 7
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cafesCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cafeCell", for: indexPath) as? TableViewCell
            cafesCell?.lblCafes?.text = cafes[indexPath.row]
            return cafesCell ?? UITableViewCell()
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
            return tableView.frame.height / 7
        }

        @IBAction func closeTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

    }

    class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

        @IBOutlet weak var lblCafes: UILabel!

        override func layoutSubviews() {
            super.layoutSubviews()

            self.lblCafes.backgroundColor = .systemOrange
            self.roundCorners(corners: [.topLeft, .bottomLeft], radius: 10)

       }
    }
```